# Quazip throws an error on Mac 10.9, Qt 5.4 and clang(64 bit)

Tags: c++, macos, qt, clang, quazip

I am trying to use Quazip 0.7.1(compiled with Qt 5.4 on the same machine using clang) in my Qt 5.4 project to zip files in an archive. The code works fine on Windows using MSVC 2012 compiler however the same code crashes on Mac OSX with error `QIODevice::open file access not specified`. Below is snippet of my code.

```
bool Utils::Archive(QList<QString> arrFiles, QString strFileName)
{
    QFile zipFile(strFileName);
    QuaZip zip(&zipFile);

    // CODE CRASHES HERE
    if(!zip.open(QuaZip::mdAppend))
    {
      qWarning("testCreate(): zip.open(): %d", zip.getZipError());
      return false;
    }
```

The code crashes on the zip.open call. Any advice/ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to indicate what version of quazip are you using (a tagged release, or if head then what revision).

Comment: I am using v0.7.1 downloaded from SourceForge project page. http://sourceforge.net/projects/quazip/files/quazip/

Answer (score 0):

Well this is my code which works fine, and from comparing it to your im calling open on the Quazip object before the Quazip file maybe try this like i said it works for me. Im usiung mdCreate but im sure this works for mdappend too

```
// Create new zip file to store the file.
auto zip_file(new QuaZip(file_path.string().c_str()));
if(zip_file->open(QuaZip::mdCreate))
{
    QuaZipFile file(zip_file);

    if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly, QuaZipNewInfo("something.xml")) == false)
    {
         // Error
    }
    else
    {
        // Do stuff...
    }
```